# Error with keypress code in node.js

Tags: node.js, stdin, keypress

I am trying out the node.js keypress module to listen for keypress events. https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress

I tried out the sample example.

```
var keypress = require('keypress');

// make `process.stdin` begin emitting "keypress" events 
keypress(process.stdin);

// listen for the "keypress" event 
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
  console.log('got "keypress"', key);
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    process.stdin.pause();
  }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

I would expect the sample code to work without error. However, I received an error

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
              ^

TypeError: process.stdin.setRawMode is not a function
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Perhaps you are trying to run the code in an IDE? Try running it from command-line;

```
$ node your_script.name.js
```